# update-grub command is not removing Windows Boot Manager

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows, xubuntu

I installed Windows 10 in another partition along with Xubuntu, and then I removed it using GParted. Tried to execute `sudo update-grub` but it's not removing the option to boot from Windows Boot Manager, but adding it again.

```
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-57-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-57-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-53-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-53-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-51-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-51-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
```

What needs to be done to completely remove it?

Comment: Do you have a distinct partition (500MB, say) for that EFI data ? Clean out the bootmanager reference. You may need to research using the "EFI shell" if your motherboard supports it. /boot/efi  should be accessible from Ubuntu though. Make a backup in any case.

Comment: Yes, I could enter in there. Remove it manually?

Answer (score 1):

Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi

to remove tha and repeat what you did before, then use the command.
Edit: what means @ after sda1, that may be the problem

Comment: No matter how many times I run, it will show it. I have no idea what the `@` means. I tried to `cd` into the folder but there's no `sda` in there.

Comment: Ok. I `cd`ed more deeply in `/boot/efi/EFI/` and removed `Microsoft` folder, ran the command but the option is still in boot order in BIOS, although when running the command it did not show the Windows Boot Manager

Comment: You say "Boot order in BIOS", that may be an EFI boot manager, so you may need to delete it using an EFI shell, your motherboard manufacturer should be to support you. Or is it the grub.cfg list ?

Answer (score 1):

Open `/etc/default/grub` with root and edit it with your editor.

Include the line `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true` in the file, then save and exit.

Now run `sudo update-grub`. The issue will be solved.